# How to set header to download file .apk or .jar?

Tags: php, joomla

I have a sample $file is test.zip or test.apk or test.jar

```
$len = filesize($file);
$filename = basename($file);
ob_end_clean();
JResponse::clearHeaders();
JResponse::setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true);
JResponse::setHeader('Expires', '0', true);
JResponse::setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);
JResponse::setHeader('Content-Type', $file, true);
JResponse::setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$filename.';', true);
JResponse::setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary', true);
JResponse::setHeader('Content-Length', $len, true);
JResponse::sendHeaders();
echo JFile::read($file);
```

When read file as test.zip is result OK, But when read file `test.apk or test.jar` is system error, How to set header to read this file (apk, jar)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

setHeader in Content-Type is

```
'apk' => 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
'jar' => 'application/java-archive'
```

More:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Comment: 'apk' => 'application/vnd.android.package-archive' header doesn't work for me with php in laravel

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
Content-type: application/jar
Content-type: application/apk
```

But i think this line of code is wrong.

```
JResponse::setHeader('Content-Type', $file, true);
```

Probabily you must use like this

```
JResponse::setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/jar', true);
```

Comment: Please use `application/vnd.android.package-archive`.

`Content-type: application/apk` is not the correct Content-type for apk, it will cause Chrome to show the "Can't open file" error (Android Download Manager (default) open file depend on correct Content-type)